# Setting cookie and redirecting in Server Action (Next.js 13.5)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I'm trying to set a cookie and redirect the user to "/" with a Server Action. Nothing new, right?

```
//page.js
export default function Page() {

  async function checkPassword(formData) {   

    'use server'

    const password = formData.get('pass')

    if (process.env.PASSWORD_PROTECT === password) {

        cookies().set('login' , "true");
        redirect('/')
    } else {
        redirect('/password')
    }

  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="grid place-content-center min-h-screen">
        <div className="flex flex-col items-center gap-4">
          <h1 className="text-2xl">This Page is Under Development... </h1>
          <p>Enter Password:</p>
          <form action={checkPassword} method="POST">
            <div className="form-control">
              <div className="input-group">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="pass"
                  className="input input-bordered"
                />
                <button className="btn" type="submit">Login</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If I remove the redirect after setting the cookie, then the server includes the set-cookie "login = true" into the request response header, so it works fine. The problem is when I try to redirect right after setting the cookie. Then somehow the user is redirected even before the server could respond with the "set-cookie" in the request response header.

Next 13.5 (using experimental server actions)

What am I doing wrong? Or is this an unexpected behavior?

Comment: did you add a `try` `catch` ? i'll gat a `NEXT_REDIRECT`, should probably find other way to redirect user

Comment: Have you found a solution @talisker? I'm running into the exact same problem and I can't find anything online. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Hi, in my case it was a bug with the "next-international" library. It was fixed by its team and now everything is working as expected.